# Displaying menu items in the Android ICS action bar

Tags: java, android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I've got an app that I've written targeting Android 2.1 which makes use of the menu button to expose some options. I'd like to have this menu available through the action bar overflow button in ICS, but I'm having trouble with getting it to show up.

If I change my target API to 15, the legacy menu button in the bottom bar disappears in ICS, but the icon in the top right of the action bar doesn't replace it, so there is no way to access the menu. I've tried adding the showAsAction attribute to the menu items, which did nothing. I'm definitely targeting 4.0.3 in my Eclipse build options.

All I want is for that menu to be accessible somewhere whilst using the ICS Holo theme, but still backwards compatible to older devices. How do I go about that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually you add those Action Items simply by implementing the `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` and adding the `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` for the desired items in the menu's XML file.

e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_save"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_save"
          android:title="@string/menu_save"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
</menu>
```

Did you consider this fact?

Edit:
Here is a simple implemantation which worked for me a while ago:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    createMenu(menu);
    return true;
}

private void createMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuItem mnu1 = menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Logout");
    {
        mnu1.setAlphabeticShortcut('a');
        mnu1.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
        mnu1.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I have the onCreateOptionsMenu implemented and showAsAction="isRoom" on all of the menu items, but there's just nothing in the action bar except for the app's name and icon.

Comment: @IneffablePigeon: Here is a sample project that works: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Menus/ActionBarBC

Comment: Try "ifRoom" rather than "isRoom".

Comment: Oops, typo. I was using 'ifRoom'. Thanks for that git page, CommonsWare.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue 5 minutes ago. Dont know if this can be still helpful, but this is how I got it solved:

Add super.setBooleanProperty("showTitle", true); to your onCreate method

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.setBooleanProperty("showTitle", true);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//more code...
```

This will force the action bar to show and the menu button replacement will be there.
I am targeting android 4 in eclipse. Older devices show the bar as title only and of course are listening to default menu button action.